# Getting new element info when using 'Sortable'

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

I have a 'calendar', which consists of 5 columns, each column has 5 divs, which are `timeslots`. I am displaying appointments in each of the `timeslots`, and have implemented the JQuery `Sortable` in order to move the appointment from one `timeslot` to another, or to another column (which represents days). I would like to implement an `AJAX` call once the movement has been complete, in order to update my database, and reflect the appointment change, in the calendar.

**The problem:**

Once I move the appointment from column `A` to column `B`, I am not sure how to get the new date and time. Normally, I would use Javascript to get this data by searching the DOM until I find the data I need. But when using the sortable, I'm not able to get the new column, as the DOM seems to still represent the old column.

**The question:**

How to get the DOM for the spot where I drop the element when I'm using the `Sortable` interface?

Here is my HTML, which is condensed for the sake of simplicity:

```
<div class="column" id="day1">
        <div class="route_container">
            <div class="date"></div>
            <button class="add_route" name="add_route" onclick="">Add New Route - 1</button>
            <div class = "truck" id="day1_route1">
                <h3>8-10</h3>
                <div class="timeslot" id="d1_1">
                    <ul class="_ts">
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a></li>
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h3>10-12</h3>
                <div class="timeslot" id="d1_2">
                    <ul class="_ts">
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a></li>
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h3>12-2</h3>
                <div class="timeslot" id="d1_3">
                    <ul class="_ts">
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a></li>
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h3>2-4</h3>
                <div class="timeslot" id="d1_4">
                    <ul class="_ts">
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a></li>
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h3>4-6</h3>
                <div class="timeslot" id="d1_5">
                    <ul class="_ts">
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a></li>
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column" id="day2">
        <div class="route_container">
            <div class="date"></div>
            <button class="add_route" name="add_route">Add New Route</button>
            <div class = "truck" id="day2_route1">
                <h3>8-10</h3>
                <div class="timeslot" id="d2_1">
                    <ul class="_ts">
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a></li>
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h3>10-12</h3>
                <div class="timeslot" id="d2_2">
                    <ul class="_ts">
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a></li>
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h3>12-2</h3>
                <div class="timeslot" id="d2_3">
                    <ul class="_ts">
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a></li>
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h3>2-4</h3>
                <div class="timeslot" id="d2_4">
                    <ul class="_ts">
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a></li>
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h3>4-6</h3>
                <div class="timeslot" id="d2_5">
                    <ul class="_ts">
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a></li>
                        <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the Javascript I'm using at the moment to move the `li` elements around:

```
$("._ts").sortable({
    connectWith: "._ts", 
    revert: "true",
    cancel: ".new_appt", 
    stop: function(){
        var date = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id'); 
        alert("this is the new date: " + date); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: ajaxurl, 
            data:{action: "update_appointments", date: date, timeslot: timeslot},
            success: function(response){
                if(response.type = "success"){
                    add_appointment(date, response.appt, col);  
                }
            }
        });
    }

});
```

As it stands, I am trying to use the `var date = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');` to get the new date from the new column, but I'm getting the old date. How can I get the new information?

Let me know if there is anything else you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
```

to:

```
$(e.toElement).parents(".column").attr("id")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mt7LF/

Comment: How would I get the text from the `<div class="date"></div>`? I add the data using jquery. I tried some of the things you suggested, but I get javascript.